# Mirroring laptop screen to TV wirelessly

Tags: windows-7, streaming, mirroring, hdtv

I have a HP DV6 laptop and a SAMSUNG UE46F6505 smart TV.

How can I connect/mirror my laptop to the TV wirelessly without an HDMI cable? Both the laptop and TV are connected the wireless router. I want to use the TV as an extra monitor for my laptop. I don't wanna buy other devices to do this. Is it possible?

Laptop configuration:

- Intel Core i7 3rd gen
- 6 GB RAM
- Windows 7
- NVIDIA GeForce graphics card

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, without additional hardware this is not possible.  I'm sorry.

Comment: I agree with this, there are many software packages but  to truly mirror the screen wirelessly without quality loss, you will need a video wireless transmitter for your laptop, I believe they come in VGA and HDMI varieties and work similarly to a cable.

Comment: why any adroid phone can do screen mirroring for free and a PC which is 100 times more powerful cant?

Answer (score 1):

Intel WIDI can do this. [You can download the software here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=3227&DwnldID=23861&ProductFamily=Wireless%20Networking&ProductLine=Wireless%20Technologies&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Wireless%20Display%20%28Intel%C2%AE%20WiDi%29&lang=eng).

Comment: Intel has discontinued support for this software and it is no longer available there.

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional hardware you cant stream your screen to the TV.

You need something like [that](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815158342&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Video%20Devices%20&%20TV%20Tuners-_-N82E16815158342&gclid=CJ6BzOGku7UCFcpDMgodU0QAYA) to connect your PC with your TV.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned not wanting to buy anything, but I would recommend doing so. Chromecast can perform [screen mirroring](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2380302):

[image]

Comment: As you recomented, I was looking for some devices. One of them is Google's Chromecast. But AFAIK it cannot mirror the screen of the laptop/pc. I am not sure if I can do it with netgear push2tv or xbox 360 or belkin screencast. do u have any any suggestion? otherwise I have to go and buy a HDMI cable (i don't like using cable).